# How can I convert xodr map into jpg or png file?

Tags: xml, image, carla

Are there any Carla experts here? I want to convert xodr file into jpg or png file but I don't know  how carla loads the xodr file. The PythonAPI's example- no-rendering-mode.py gives me some idea. But i cannot find the xodr file that carla use.
I also use opendrive2lanlet to implement but how opendrive2lanelet can draw map? Is this way practicable?
If there is any answer helpful, I would appreciate a lot.

1. some attempt on opendrive2lanelet. If xml file can be drawn, it is practicable.

```
def main():
    with open('util/opendrive/TownBig.xodr', 'r') as f:
        opendrive = parse_opendrive(etree.parse(f).getroot())

    for road in opendrive.roads:
        plan_view = road.planview
```

2. code examples about no rendering mode in PythonAPI/examples, it can download map as jpg file through carla client but I don't know which xodr file it use.
   https://github.com/carla-simulator/carla/blob/master/PythonAPI/examples/no_rendering_mode.py

Comment: Do you have OSM.  See https://carla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tuto_G_openstreetmap/#convert-openstreetmap-format-to-opendrive-format